# Shinyapp not loading

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

Wrote a very simple script for an shiny app and nothing shows up in the window that pops up. When I click open in browser it throws an error connection timed out.
Here's the script that I ran:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage("Hello world")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There are no errors on the console or terminal that shows up, I have no idea why it's not showing up. Ran the same code in 3 different machines and it worked, just doesn't work on my desktop.

I'm currently on version 3.6.2 of base r and 1.1463 for Rstudio. Desktop is running Windows 10 x64
Steps I have tried so far:
1. Completely uninstalled R and Rstudio and reinstalled (Same issue)
2. Reverted back to older version of R (Same Issue)
3. Updated to the new version of Rstudio (New version of Rstudio itself would not open)
4. Computer was restarted multiple times throughout the process.

Would appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCief.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jneKT.png)

Answer (score 1):

the code is not the problem, I was able to run it locally with RStudio 1.2.5033 and R version 3.6.2 on a Win 10 Pro 64 bit machine 1909 and on shinyapps.io (https://abenedetti.shinyapps.io/Test/).

Can you try to update RStudio?
Did you tried on the cloud https://rstudio.cloud/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason in my work computer the latest version of R studio would not run. I'm assuming it might be because it's not installed as an administrator in the c:drive. I ended up installing an older version that my employer allows me to install in the c:drive and shiny is working properly in that version of r studio.